# Run app backgroundmode

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

Okay, but I have seen, that apple reject the distribution process, if you are playing silent musik, to run the app continue :( Is there a other way to run it in backgroundmode ?

Comment: Are you talking about a jailbreak solution? If so, you could create a mobile substrate daemon.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS timed background processing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245763/ios-timed-background-processing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to play music in the background is to register it with the approved apple methods for playing in the background. If you try and override these methods or attempt to play music in the background another way, you will more than likely be rejected.

You can read up on how to handle your app in the various background states and available multitasking operations available.

[Apple Background Tasks Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3)