# IOS schedule action in fixed interval

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app that I want it to schedule an action to be done in fixed interval say 5 mins even if the app is closed.

Comment: you can use [performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:](http://www.pawapps.com/2011/08/06/quick-code-performselectorwithobjectafterdelay/) to schedule actions, but I don't think it is possible when the app is closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245763/ios-timed-background-processing

Comment: Thanks but is there is any other way to schedule it when the app is closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *no way* for your app to schedule *itself* to run if its closed (i.e. terminated)

If its in the background it still cannot schedule itself to run *on a fixed interval*, but it can run at in response to certain external events and at the discretion of the OS.

You could post multiple local notifications before the app closes and then *if* the user clicks on one then your app would run. But posting a notification to the user every 5 minutes would be an absolutely appallingly bad thing to do and would probably result in the app being rejected from the app store.

There are certain options such as local notifications and push notifications and background fetch if you have a *low* frequency, which is not regular but irregular. But 5 minutes is short a time period so its totally out of the question to have any solution at all.

In summary there is:
a) Absolutely no way of scheduling something in the background in a *regular* manner (all the alternative are irregular: local push depends on user input, remote push depends on delivery time of the notification; background fetch depends upon when the OS decides it will execute your app, etc. etc. 
b) Scheduling something irregularly on a *frequent* basis is simply not possible

Answer (score 2):

First, when the app is running in foreground you can use NSTimer to perform set of actions after specific time interval.
Second, when the app is running in background you cannot do all kind of operations however you can do following things,

1. Play Audio
2. VOIP services
3. Fetch content from the network on a regular
   basis.
4. Use remote notifications as a signal to download new content
   available from network.

Last two background mode can launch or resume your app in background and perform required action. But any operation other than what is intended by each background mode will lead to app store rejection. So, if you operation fits in any of these you are good to go,

For more information you can look at this link under Background modes https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: "Last two background mode can launch or resume your app in background and perform required action. So, if you operation fits in any of these you are good to go". You cannot fetch content on a regular basis - it is the OS that decides when your app will be run, not you, you have no control over this, you can give an indication of the frequency you would like but the OS decides, and it certainly would not run as often as 5 minutes. Also sending a remote push every 5 minutes is too much and would probably get your app server rejected by the apple push servers.